# Using variables in SSIS

Tags: c#, ssis

I'm trying to calculate variable, based on gathered data:
[image]

in Script Component:

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
 double OrderByPrice;
 OrderByPrice = Dts.Variables["User::UnitPrice"] *   Dts.Variables["User::Factor"];      
}
```

but

> 'Dts' don't exist in the current context.

What I do wrong?

Comment: This might be better done in a derived column transform than a script transform

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the usage Type in the screenshot of your Script Component, your variables are ReadOnly, change UnitPrice to Write.

Also ypu access variables in a script component via the Row object like so:

```
Row.unitprice
```